# 2D list filling a whole column

Tags: python, arrays, list, adjacency-matrix

I want an algorithm that makes an adjacency matrix. The input is a 1D list and it outputs an 2D list with how the numbers changed. This is what I have:

```
n_clusters = 5
user = [4, 4, 4, 2, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0]  # input array

movement_counts = [[0] * n_clusters] * n_clusters  # row is from, col is to

prev_label = user[0]
for label in user[1:]:
    if label != prev_label:
        movement_counts[prev_label][label] += 1
    prev_label = label
```

This returns

```
[[1, 0, 1, 1, 0], 
 [1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
 [1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
 [1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
 [1, 0, 1, 1, 0]]
```

But I want it to return this:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]]
```

Why is it filling the whole column with numbers instead of just one element?

Comment: can you elaborate how to get this output based on the input user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
movement_counts = [[0] * n_clusters] * n_clusters
```

with:

```
movement_counts = [[0] * n_clusters for _ in range(n_clusters)]
```

Because, `movement_counts = [[0] * n_clusters] * n_clusters` generates the list that contains sublists that point to same reference inside memory, so if you change any of element inside any of the sublist the change will occur in all the sublists.